# What better url?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

### What better url?

**this:**

```
Forum/{forumId}/Section/{sectionId}/Thread/{threadId}/
```

for example:

```
Forum/1/Section/2/Thread/3
```

when the topic with ID = 3 is contained in the section with ID = 2, which is contained in the forum with ID = 1, return some view, otherwise(topic with id=3 is contained in the section with ID = 5) return 404 error

---

**or simply**

```
Forum/{ForumId}
Section/{SectionId}
Thread/{ThreadId}
```

Comment: option 1 seems better since each thread would have a forum id and a section id and would be more SEO friendly. Navigation would also be more easy.

Comment: Thanks, but probably I will implement both options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URLs should have the following features:

1. Identifiers so you know what to display
2. A description of the content so the user can tell what they'll be seeing by glancing at a URL
3. A description of the content so you maximise your Search Engine Optimisation.

With this in mind, I'd suggest the following, which is a variation on option 2:

For a forum:

```
Forum/{forumId}/{forumName}
```

For a section:

```
Section/{sectionId}/{forumName}/{sectionName}
```

For a thread:

```
Thread/{threadId}/{forumName}/{sectionName}/{threadTitle}
```

You won't actually use the included `forumName`, `sectionName` and `threadTitle`, but they help with points 2 and 3 above.

Comment: this URL can be veeeeeery long, and user can not navigate through the forum by removing the right side of the url

Comment: That's a fair point, but keep in mind that a large majority of users use navigation to navigate rather than URL hacking. myforumsite.com/1/2/3 tells you nothing about what you're going to see by clicking on it.

Comment: this not a question of security, as I said I want to URL was part of the interface

Comment: I didn't mean 'hacking' in the sense of security, I just meant manual editing of browser addresses. Up to you, though :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I have some trouble with English=)

Answer (score 2):

i also think first one is better but is it necessary to show the text (Forum, Section or Thread) in url, you can make it like this:

```
Forum/{forumId}/{sectionId}/{threadId}/
```

which'll be displayed like this in your url

```
http://www.yourwebsite.com/Forum/1/2/3
```

and by this you'll achieve the samething you are trying to do that ...

Comment: I agree, but I would prefer Forum/{forumId}/{sectionId}/{threadId}/

Comment: then just add Forum to it like Forum/{forumId}/{sectionId}/{threadId}/

Comment: That's exactly what i just wrote ^^

Comment: sorry missed out ... but did you got your answer or wanting to something different?

Comment: http://www.yourwebsite.com/1/2/3 this URL hard to understand, users do not know what  mean this numbers, but shorter

Comment: I agree with @Topol-M - yourwebsite.com/1/2/3 is meaningless to a user or a search engine spider.

Answer (score 1):

I think those are nested resources. I would prefer shallow routes....

- **Forums/** - all forums (if available)
- **Forums/1** - forum id 1 and display all sections
- **Sections/1** - section 1 index [all threads] (*you won't need forum id since section is nested resources of forum*)
- **Threads/1** - thread id 1 (*nested resources*)

IMO, the shorter URL, the easier to remember. :)

Comment: http://Forum/Threads/1 - thread id 1 (nested resources), but what happens if the user has to remove part of the URL to return to the list of all topics? I want to URl was also part of the user interface